# Create SVG element via javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

I need to create this structure using only javascript:

```xml
<svg>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#circle"></use>
</svg>
```

But I have trouble with creating `xmlns:xlink` attribute. Here is my js code:

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
var use = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
// throws error here
use.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns', 'xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
use.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '#circle');
svg.appendChild(use);
```

If I comment string with settings `xmlns:xlink` all working good and makes svg same as above, but without `xmlns:xlink`.

I seen a lot of question similar to mine, but they didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I guess about this, but how we can set `xmlns:xlink` attribute?

Comment: @RobertLongson, wow, you right! Now all working and look fine. Can you format your previous comment as question for sharing you knowledge (it will be more noticeable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding

```
use.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns', 'xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
```

You don't need that line and actually it's not valid.

The xmlns:xlink attribute set automatically when you create an element with createElementNS or an attribute with setAttributeNS if you're creating an element/attribute in an XML document and it's not required if you're creating an element in a html document.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
// "circle" may be any tag name
var shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");

// Set any attributes as desired
shape.setAttribute("cx", 25);
shape.setAttribute("cy", 25);
shape.setAttribute("r",  20);
shape.setAttribute("fill", "green");

// Add to a parent node; document.documentElement should be the root svg element.
// Acquiring a parent element with document.getElementById() would be safest.
document.documentElement.appendChild(shape);
```

Comment: I need to do this without editing HTML. And creating circle I don't need too. Just use.